# Why Apex email send works with a static list

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, email

Want to send mail from APEX, From the LWC UI component, I send the following email list and get an error.

**To remove the double-quote from the email string and put in the string list I used the following syntax**

```
 List<String> emails;
      if (toAddressesArray != '') {
        emails = toAddressesArray.replace('\"', '').split(',', 0);
      }


Email list
[demo@gmail.com,unboxxdemo@gmail.com]

On apex set 
toAddresses:::([demo@gmail.com, unboxxdemo@gmail.com])

Error
failed::SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS,
Email address is invalid: [demo@gmail.com: [toAddresses, [demo@gmail.com]
```

Emails are valid, when I used a static list it's work perfectly, but it not work with a dynamic list.

```
static list                
  new List<String>{ 'smith@gmail.com' }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

toAddressesArray appears to be a String. As such, you're probably serializing it from JSON. The following should fix the problem:

```
emails = (String[])JSON.deserialize(toAddressesArray, List<String>.class);
```

Or, you could change your parameter to be a `String[]` instead of `String`, in which case you wouldn't need any further manipulation.